# Trying to hide a parent component on a specific page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So far the way me and my group have our app setup is that our navigation SideBar wraps all the pages so we don't have to pass it to every single page but I would like to hide in the login page, is there anyway to just hide it when the user is on the login page?

here's my routes

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <Router>
                <SideBar>
                    <Container maxWidth="xl" disableGutters={true}>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/homepage" component={Homepage} />
                            <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />                          
                            <Route exact path="/dualFinder" component={DualFinder} />
                            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                            <Route exact path="/AboutChampion" component={AboutChampion} />
                            <Route component={Homepage} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Container>
                </SideBar>
                <Footer />
            </Router>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you please provide more details. these are just routes and the aren't visible anywhere. show your login  page code from where you want to hide the route,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with conditional rendering. For example, you can use the `useLocation` hook from React Router to know when the user is on the login page. If the user is on the login page you do not render the side bar. Something like this:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const location=useLocation()

...
return(
.....
  {location==="your login pathname"?<DONT RENDER SIDEBAR>:<RENER SIDEBAR>}
.....
)
```

Comment: no need for "if". remove if and it will work fine :)

Comment: also, you can use `null` in the ternary expression `{ location==="your login pathname" ? null : <RENER SIDEBAR> }`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the prop to Sidebar component called `<Sidebar visible={visible} />` and the Sidebar component will be rendered only visible is `true`. And you can move the sidebar component down a few component so you can use `useHistory` and `useLocation` hooks from `react-router-dom`